# Create horizon plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

I have the following example data and want to create a horizon plot, showing the changes in `area` column over the `year`. Any suggestion on doing this using `ggplot2`?

```
year <- 1990:2005
area1 <- runif(16, 18,20)
area2 <- runif (16,6,6.7)
area3 <- runif(16, 7,8)
dat <- data.frame(year, area1, area2, area3)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a horizon plot using `ggplot_horizon` from the `ggTimeSeries` package. Your data sample is a bit sparse for a good horizon plot, so I've created some fake data. The example below is based on the example in the [`ggTimeSeries` vignette](https://www.ggplot2-exts.org/ggTimeSeries.html).

```
# Fake data
set.seed(1)
df = data.frame(x = rep(1:1000,3), y = cumsum(rnorm(3000)) + 50, 
                group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=1000))

#devtools::install_github("Ather-Energy/ggTimeSeries")
#install.packages("viridis")
library(ggTimeSeries)
library(viridis)

ggplot_horizon(df, 'x', 'y', vcGroupingColumnNames='group', bandwidth=10) +
  facet_grid(group ~ .) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option="inferno")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, these should be separate form each other so that they you have 3 horizontal plots and the color scheme represents the value.

Comment: When you say "the color scheme represents the value," are you saying you want the color to vary horizontally within a ribbon based on the height of the ribbon?

Comment: yes, I want something like this: [link] (http://www.r-bloggers.com/horizon-plots-with-ggplot-not/)

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you're looking for but start with this structure and go from there.

```
dat <- reshape2::melt(dat, id.var = "year")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_point()
```